# postgressql query matching a field containing domainname

Tags: postgresql

Need help with postsql query field matching a certain domain names in the end as per below in a particular FIELD.
1234.abc.xyz.com;
0971.abc.xyz.com

```
WHERE CAST (domain_name AS text) LIKE  '%\d{4}.abc.xyz.com%'
```

#where domain_name is the FIELD name

Answer (score 1):

~ is used for regular expression matching, LIKE for simple matching.  Read more about them here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP

If you just want to find domain_name that end in a particular text, the simple matching works fine (don't know if you really need the cast):

```
select * from tbl_test where domain_name LIKE '%.abc.xyz.com'
```

This will not work correctly:

```
select * from tbl_test where domain_name ~ '\d\d\d\d.abc.xyz.com'
```

The dot (.) is "any character" in a regular expression so this domain would be selected: abcd.abcxxyzdcom.  You need to escape the dot in the string for it to be treated literally like this: '\d\d\d\d\.abc\.xyz\.com'

Underscore is a wildcard for "any character" in the simple LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

use ~ followed by your search pattern as regular expression:

```
where domain_name ~ '\d\d\d\d\.abc\.xyz\.com'
```

playground:
https://dbfiddle.uk/O0Q_Ctmo

```
create table tbl_test (
  domain_name varchar
);


insert into tbl_test VALUES 
('1234.abc.xyz.com'),
('0971.abc.xyz.com'),
('0971.abc.xyz.bam'),
('1234.xxx.xyz.com'),
('123.xxx.xyz.com'),
('aaaa.xxx.xyz.com')
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

> ```
> INSERT 0 6
> ```

```
select * from tbl_test
where domain_name ~ '\d\d\d\d\.abc\.xyz\.com'
```

| domain_name |
| --- |
| 1234.abc.xyz.com |
| 0971.abc.xyz.com |

> ```
> SELECT 2
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O0Q_Ctmo)